# Multiple Textures House Model Export as FBX to Roblox doesn't work

Tags: modeling, mesh, export

Basically, I am trying to export my house model has multipules texture as a single mesh into roblox.
when I export model as fbx without joining parts into single model its looks ok.
but if I join all parts and make it single mesh the exported model, mesh's texture in roblox appear very bad.
 
My house model has multiple textures materials for different parts like ground, walls, windows, gates, doors, borders all are separate model and has different texture materials.

Texture Bake option I use are

- Render engine Is cycle.
- Bake is Diffuse, Only Color.
- All unwrapping option including Smart UV Project.

Option so far I have tried

- All Texture Materials parts are targeting same single UV MAP single UV Texture png file.
- All Texture Materials parts are targeting same single UV MAP Diffent UV Texture png files.
- All Texture Materials parts are targeting Different UV MAP and each model generating different png files after then combined all png in to udmi files.
  Like in the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYMM8nphppk

and also and done many tires but yet failed,

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.